# Unix Time Subtraction error?

Tags: unix, timestamp, epoch

Start 6/7/2018 13:00 - End 7/14/2018 10:00 = Unix Time 3186000

The above is 35 days and 23 hours, converted to seconds is 3106800

So the manual conversion is 22 minutes different (less) from converting the date/times to Unix Time Stamps and subtracting.

Why?

Comment: Isn't  it 36 days, 21 hours? That's 3186000 seconds.

Comment: Your right! I (and others) can't count/add/subtract Date/Time and that is the reason for moving to the Unix Timestamp to solve for seconds used between two dates. Thanks!